# How to stop a sprites physicsBody from moving?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

In my SpriteKit game i move several sprites using `[sprite.physicsBody applyImpulse:vector];` but at a specific point i the game i want them to stop. 
I already tried to apply the exact opposite impulse.. but that did not worked very well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly set a physicsBody's velocity via the velocity property. Stop a body by setting it's velocity to (0,0):

```
sprite.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0,0);
```